# Laravel shows page 403 after form submission with French characters

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using https://ckeditor.com/ and everything works great, except if I introduce french text, such as:

```
une variété d'alternatives pratiques
vous informer sur l'offre existante
```

The single quote is making the form submission to go into Laravel 404 error. The amazing thing is that the endpoint is not even reached

**HTML**:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('update-customer') }}" accept-charset="UTF-8">
   <textarea name="description"></textarea>   
</form>
```

**PHP**:

```
Route::post('/update-customer', 'CustomersController@update')->name('update-customer');
// ....
public function update(Request $request)
{
   echo 'Testing';
   die();
}
```

**The "Testing" works**:

```
Hello, how are you?
How you doin'?
```

**The "Testing" does not work:**

```
une variété d'alternatives pratiques
vous informer sur l'offre existante
```

Also, I don't have any error in `storage/logs` nor in the `root` folder.

---

**UPDATE (1)**

The request being sent:

General:

```
Request URL: https://mywebsite.com/update-customer
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 403 
Remote Address: [...]
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

Response headers:

```
cache-control: no-cache, private
content-encoding: gzip
content-length: 927
content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
date: Tue, 30 Nov 2021 21:16:10 GMT
referrer-policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
server: Apache
set-cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6IkU5SEd6QmxndEltSysvN1JiUW90b0E9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiWm9RVXNhMUN0eGZLSVBBMkM4c05OM1BaMFVJTCt4QVhtZmZ3UEwyUUFjcGxoWmcxY1cxU0xNV1YwMHdoRmZ5dzZneitkRENDM05IcnRzR0wvbDdIR0NKWjJQeTQ0NW5hSmM1dFkyWnJ3ekh4ZTdyTVI0UVRxMTFuam1iYnNJUWEiLCJtYWMiOiIwNDg0YWYxMTQ3MjM3ZTc0Y2FiMGEwNjBiNzEzODEwNjNiYzdjY2NlNmQ4ZDEyOThmMmNlOWFlOGYxMzRhNzc2In0%3D; expires=Tue, 30-Nov-2021 23:16:11 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; samesite=lax
set-cookie: mywebsite_session=eyJpdiI6ImNVUXIwYzA0Q09oTE84UUd3OERydXc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoicTQ2UXVnQm94ZGZYYjF6RVRLOUNaVFVJR0hacWtVVkhweFZOTnJHOGNiM2kwQ1hWVGZadTBFa1hVMytSTThVMnc0VHBEWURHZ2dDcHFhNzIvVHRFY1ZIVnlVR2JKdGYrbElQN3V0bUpOY1l6RDFXdkx1SlZHdDFINlNhaFFhT2EiLCJtYWMiOiJkMGU4NmVhNzc4MmViOGE5MWNmNmI4Nzg5MTllMjAxZTQ2YzlmOThhNzY0MDkxOWEzMWJkYmZmZTJiMGZjYTk1In0%3D; expires=Tue, 30-Nov-2021 23:16:11 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; httponly; samesite=lax
strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload
strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000
vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
x-powered-by: PHP/7.4.26
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
```

Request headers

```
:authority: mywebsite.com
:method: POST
:path: /update-customer
:scheme: https
accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,pt;q=0.7
cache-control: max-age=0
content-length: 5228
content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundarycQscCJKoPCxc2BC7
cookie: _ga=GA1.1.1429237055.1629733241; timezone=Europe/London; _ga_GF77T7T4YZ=GS1.1.1629984694.4.1.1629985960.0; roundcube_cookies=enabled; webmailsession=info%40mywebsite.com%3aGLHEoJXrtL1kfJDU%2cb4b76b27d9d81c98aa359c066dd4e792; roundcube_sessauth=hqif7tJ6XoCPgh0Dr9AIoOKkoOhr5egh-1633533000; cpsession=mywebsite%3a2A4g0gXz9_EwvTAl%2c6e3e0fea0af2471ccdabb283666adaeb; XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6InJLQnE2bmVLK0VxWWtxdi9oNDdvVkE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiUTRrOGVrR05xaE5DbHlCVjRyZEwxOXQ1UHByTnRROURhdDBUZGJ1RWVGZjZGQ3pnU0lwUWcveWdGOU43amVzYzVNYlBUV1hFRzhhNnozcDNIdjJ6eFRpMmFYMDEvcUJrS29yZ1ZITXZuTU1EMEhncHlHSkdjWmtweHpsZXZsU3kiLCJtYWMiOiIwYjc0ZmI1ODcxN2E3NjFjMTUwZTEyOGM1NGE5YjM0ZTcxZDc1YzQ5Mzg2ZTM4ZGNlMmI0MWFjMzIwNmE1ODMyIn0%3D; mywebsite_session=eyJpdiI6IkNwNkN6QVNGdkhuZXY0Mm1IbDBXZXc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiOC8rbzNDNjl5SG5EQmMvMkhVRW5tWU1CNFN0Uld2NUg5a3RVM0xaRmdFUjdvcHJEb1JjeGU1Zk1sM2VSakdLMVFpbEY4aVNLTnBxZ1NoN004MW5BbjdjY002SGRYNzh0QkRCajE0L0ppOU1Uc21ZN3dOZUZsUTdPdTI0OGxYckgiLCJtYWMiOiI1NTAxNjRhNGIyOTJhMDRkYmNmNDExYTcxMDRkZWIzYTEzZjU2Zjk1YmIxMDkwMWFhYWZiNTQxMDNmYmFiNmVmIn0%3D
origin: https://mywebsite.com
referer: https://mywebsite.com/update-customer
sec-fetch-dest: document
sec-fetch-mode: navigate
sec-fetch-site: same-origin
sec-fetch-user: ?1
upgrade-insecure-requests: 1
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.182 Safari/537.36
```

Form Data

```
_token: Lj2XuKrw6eM1XyLSNdT8drFdYZzwG8AAh0WPYsGw
id: 22
name: John Snow
description: <pre>
<code>une vari&eacute;t&eacute; d&#39;alternatives pratiques</code></pre>
```

The HTML:

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => 'update-customer', 'autocomplete' => 'off', 'enctype'=>' multipart/form-data', 'files'=>'true', 'class' => '"form-horizontal form-material']) !!}
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="22">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name">
    <textarea name="description" rows="5"></textarea>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

The route (NO MIDDLEWARE):

```
Route::post('/update-customer', function()
{
  die('Just testing..');
}->name('update-customer');
```

---

**UPDATE (2)**

This is getting weirder as time goes by.

**Does not work:**

```
hello d'alternatives
```

**Works:**

```
hello da'lternatives
hello dal'ternatives
hello dalt'ernatives
hello dalternatives
```

Comment: So is it 404 like the title, or 403? In devtools, can you see the network request, click on it, inspect what is sent? How about the rendered HTML in the browser, does the form, and the `action`, look like what you expect? `accept-charset` on your form is the only strange looking thing I can see - have you tried removing that?

Comment: @Don'tPanic it's 403, updated the post. I removed the `accept-charset` but the problem remains, this automatically added by laravel `form-open` function.

My post contains the data being sent.

Comment: The contents of a post are absolutely not going to result in a 403 error unless you have some kind of custom validation or middleware in the way. Whatever this editor is shouldn't have any bearing on the question, you should disable it as part of your debugging, no need to mention it in the question.

Comment: "*this automatically added by laravel form-open function*" - that is not what you showed us ...?  Please edit your question and show us your **real** code. You didn't confirm if the rendered form (the plain HTML in view->source) looks OK, and specifically if the form `action` is correct and what you expect.

Comment: @miken32 yes it is resulting in 403 ONLY because of the content written in the input. I even did the following: `Route::post('/update-customer', function()
    {
        die('yey');
    })->name('update-customer');` and this function ONLY runs if it's not filled with that phrase. I don't even have any middleware between.

Comment: @Don'tPanic the `Form::open` function from laravel translates into an HTML like I wrote in my post. Is basically the same as writing `<form ....>`. Writing with laravel function or not the outcome as HTML is the same.

Comment: View source, copy the form HTML, remove extraneous elements, and edit your question to include it.

Comment: @miken32 take a look at my post now

Comment: I am aware what "*laravel form-open*" does.  The point is you need to check the generated HTML that the browser is actually using.  You keep saying you've shown us HTML but in fact you're showing us the PHP in your Blade files.  I'll ask one more time - check the rendered HTML (view -> source), and specifically the form `action`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**.

Everything was correct with my code, it's a problem with CKEditor (that I don't know why).

By switching to TinyMCE or Froala everything works great.